# How to use in a submodule a exception created in module (in ocaml)

Tags: module, ocaml

I have a module type  `A` with an exception. `A` will be implemented by `B` and `C`

```
module type A = sig
  type t
  val f: t->t->t
  exception DivisionParZero
end


module B : A = struct
  type t = int
  let f a b=
    if (a==0) then raise DivisionParZero else b/a
  end
end
```

Ocamlc says when it compiles B:

> Error: This variant expression is expected to have type exn
>          The constructor DivisionParZero does not belong to type exn

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Your title suggests that you've misunderstood the concepts of module signature and implementation. `A` is not a moudle, and `B` is not a sub-module of `A`. `A` is a signature, *i.e.* a declaration of what is inside a given module, and `B` is a module that use `A` as its signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` is a signature that `B` needs to fulfill. In your context it means that you have to write the declaration line again:

```
module B : A = struct
  type t = int
  exception DivisionParZero
  let f a b=
    if (a==0) then raise DivisionParZero else b/a
end
```

You can experiment a little by returning a random value instead of raising the exception and you will see that the compiler tells you that your implementation does not fit the signature:

```
Error: Signature mismatch:
   Modules do not match:
     sig type t = int val f : int -> int -> int end
   is not included in
     A
   The extension constructor `DivisionParZero' is required but not provided
   File "test.ml", line 4, characters 2-27: Expected declaration
```